# Declare an UIView on app delegate

Tags: iphone, sdk

i have problem with showing an UIView on app delegate ... there is no place  on interface builder to connect IBOutlet with app delegate .

```
 [self.view addSubview:UIVIEW];   //doesn't work
```

Comment: Did we happen to answer your question? If so please check an answer.

Comment: i figured out myself ,, but thank you :) OK i'll check em all ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chances are you don't want to display anything in the app delegate. Typically when you start a new project there will be a MainViewController which is where you want to put new views and such into.

If you don't have that then you'll want to add it to the window property of the app delegate.

Answer (score 1):

your app delegate should have a `UIWindow` (almost always called `window`). Add your view as a subview to it (note: dont forget to `makeKeyAndVisible` your window!)

Check out any of the basic documentation examples for how to use a UIWindow and how to connect it in IB.